# Is there a way to use FINDSTR with non-ASCII (in this case Japanese/Chinese) characters in batch?

Tags: batch-file, unicode, findstr

I have a list of Japanese Kanji and their pronunciations saved in a text file (JouyouKanjiReadings.txt) like this

```
亜   ア
哀   アイ,あわれ,あわれむ
愛   アイ
悪   アク,オ,わるい
握   アク,にぎる
圧   アツ
(each gap is made by pressing TAB)
```

and I have a script like this

```
@echo off
set /p text=Enter here: 
echo %text%>Search.txt
echo.
findstr /G:"Search.txt" JouyouKanjiReadings.txt || echo No Results && pause > nul && exit
pause > nul
```

However, when I run the script, I always get "No Results". I tried with English characters and it worked fine. I also tried the same script with this

```
findstr "%text%" JouyouKanjiReadings.txt || echo No Results && pause > nul && exit
```

but got the same results. Is there any ways to get around this? Also, I'm displaying the these characters  correctly in the command prompt by using

```
chcp 65001
```

and a different font.

Comment: Maybe try Cygwin grep?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) (which supports Unicode but not regex) instead of [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) (which supports regex but not Unicode). See [Why are there both FIND and FINDSTR programs, with unrelated feature sets?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121128-00/?p=5963)

```
D:\kanji>chcp
Active code page: 65001

D:\kanji>find "哀" JouyouKanjiReadings.txt

---------- JOUYOUKANJIREADINGS.TXT
哀      アイ,あわれ,あわれむ
```

Redirect to `NUL` to suppress the output if you don't need it

That said, `find` isn't a good solution either. Nowadays you should use PowerShell instead of cmd with all of its quirks due to compatibility legacy issues. PowerShell fully supports Unicode and can run any .NET framework methods. To search for strings you can use the cmdlet [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7) or its alias `sls`

```
PS D:\kanji> Select-String '握'  JouyouKanjiReadings.txt

JouyouKanjiReadings.txt:5:握    アク,にぎる
```

If fact you don't even need to use UTF-8 and codepage 65001. Just store the file in UTF-16 with BOM (that'll result in a much smaller file because your file contains mostly Japanese characters), then `find` and `sls` will automatically do a search in UTF-16

Of course if there are a lot of existing batch code then you can call PowerShell from cmd like this

```
powershell -Command "Select-String '哀'  JouyouKanjiReadings.txt"
```

But if it's entirely new then please just avoid the hassle and use PowerShell